# wrong key selection from dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

So I wrote a program that converted alphabets from a sentence to numbers. To understand whether the number was in the same word or another I made a distinction with "-" and "*-". If a word is in the same line the numbers are separated by a "-" and if they are in another word they are separated by a "*-". Like hi hi => 8-5-*-8-5-.

Now I was writing a program to do the opposite i.e convert numbers to alphabets using a dictionary. I wrote the dictionary like this -

```py
Dictionary = {"26" : "z","25" : "y","24" : "x","23" : "w","22" : "v","21" : "u","20" : "t","19" : "s","18" : "r","17" : "q","16" : "p","15" : "o","14" : "n","13" : "m","12" : "l","11" : "k","10" :"j","1" : "a","2" : "b","3" : "c","4" : "d","5" : "e","6" : "f","7" : "g","8" : "h","9" : "i","*" : " "}

user_input = input("Please Enter a message: ")
count = user_input.count("-")
individual_number = user_input.split("-")

for i in range(0 , count):
  for number in individual_number[i]:
    individual_number[i] = individual_number[i].replace(number, Dictionary[number])
    
  print(individual_number[i])
```

Now it Works for numbers from 1 - 9 but for 10 - 26, it does not work. For Example -

```
8-9-*-2-6- => h
              i
              
              b
              f
```

But the same is for this one as well -

```
8-9-*-26- => h
             i
             
             bf    (This should have been "Z")
```

I don't understand why it does that. it should take the whole number instead of taking each number one by one. Please help.

Also, I want it to print the whole sentence in one line/string. But I can't get it to do it. Please help with that too.
Thank you

Comment: Your Dictionary specification has a syntax error. Are you sure it's like that? Also, why does 26 equate to 'Y'?

Comment: What syntax error ? Please explain. And sorry 26 is not equal to Y it is equal to Z that was miswritten

Comment: There was a missing quote that has since be added by another user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To convert numbers to words use this one.

```py
Dictionary = {"26" : "z","25" : "y","24" : "x","23" : "w","22" : "v","21" : "u","20" : "t","19" : "s","18" : "r","17" : "q","16" : "p","15" : "o","14" : "n","13" : "m","12" : "l","11" : "k","10" :"j","1" : "a","2" : "b","3" : "c","4" : "d","5" : "e","6" : "f","7" : "g","8" : "h","9" : "i","*" : " "}


user_input = input("Please Enter a message: ")
user_input = user_input.split('-')


output = ''
for a in user_input:
    try:
        output+=Dictionary[a]
    except KeyError:
        output+=''

print(output)
```

And for words to numbers use this one.

```py
Dictionary = {"26" : "z","25" : "y","24" : "x","23" : "w","22" : "v","21" : "u","20" : "t","19" : "s","18" : "r","17" : "q","16" : "p","15" : "o","14" : "n","13" : "m","12" : "l","11" : "k","10" :"j","1" : "a","2" : "b","3" : "c","4" : "d","5" : "e","6" : "f","7" : "g","8" : "h","9" : "i","*" : " "}
Dictionary_ = {value:key for key,value in Dictionary.items()}

user_input = input("Please Enter a message: ")

output = ''
for a in user_input:
    try:
        output+=Dictionary_[a]
        output+='-'
    except KeyError:
        output+=''
    
output = output[:-1]
print(output)
```

Comment: I think your answer is the best because it is very similar to what my starting idea to this project was. Genuinly I kinda feel stupid reading your answer. It would have been much easier if instead of replace each term, I could just find the counter value of the key from the dictionary and then just add it up in a new string. Thank you so much for helping me. Cheers :)

Comment: User inputs '27-A'. What happens then? But it's the accepted answer so presumably the OP isn't interested in robust code.

Comment: @LancelotduLac Check now.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're over-complicating things. Why the nested loop?

This seems to do what you want:

```
Dictionary = {"26" : "z","25" : "y","24" : "x","23" : "w","22" : "v","21" : "u","20" : "t","19" : "s","18" : "r","17" : "q","16" : "p","15" : "o","14" : "n","13" : "m","12" : "l","11" : "k","10" :"j","1" : "a","2" : "b","3" : "c","4" : "d","5" : "e","6" : "f","7" : "g","8" : "h","9" : "i","*" : " "}

user_input = input("Please Enter a message: ")
individual_number = user_input.split("-")

for number in individual_number:
        print(Dictionary[number],end='')
```

Comment: `print(Dictionary[number])` this should be  `print(Dictionary[number],end='')`

Comment: oh you're right! I missed OP's last sentence. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: What happens if the user inputs '27'?

Comment: Hey thank you so much for helping me. You are right I was overcomplicating things with trying to replace the original input sentence with the counter value from the dictionary. I should have just created a new sentence. thank you so much. Cheers :)

Comment: @LancelotduLac KeyErrors aren't necessarily a bad thing, it helps detecting faulty inputs. but in the end it's OP's decision

Comment: @LancelotduLac We can use try and except and put out a notification for that ?

Comment: @Tranbi What is OP ?

Comment: @CodeSpec OP = Original Poster, in this case yourself ;-)